# Can I use bit-src to collect components from different React's UI framework

Tags: reactjs, bit-src

I need to make a bit-src place that hold my React components from different React UI framework, so I found that bit can make it easy, however how can I push React UI's components from many React UI into bit.into bit-src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(disclaimer - I help maintain [Bit](https://github.com/teambit/bit)) You can export components from various projects to the same collection, thus creating your curated collection of components you use in your projects.

Each component can have its own build/test process. Components are completely detached from each other in regards to their build processes. So you can have components from different frameworks in the same collection.

Organizing the collection is something you control. Do whatever fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you, however could I install component from UI without need to call it from its library every time I need, then maybe push it to bit-src ?

Comment: Yes. you will be able to install the components directly from the collection, without going through the library itself.

Comment: I've tried with bootstrap and push it up to bit,
BTW, I'm using CRA, so I push the import of bootstrap in the entry point (index.js)
but the bit dosn't recognize this, and render the button without styling it >